# websockets on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, swift, iphone, websocket

I'm creating a mobile app that has an instant messaging capability. I am coming up with the backend before I will employ someone to develop the mobile component. The main way for communication between the mobile device (client) and server will be via a websocket. I've heard that once an application is no longer in the foreground on mobile devices (both android and iOS) the websocket closes.I don't wantt to spend the time developing the server around websockets to realise i can't use this technology for this purpose down the line. Could someone please assist me with the following questions:

1. If this is the case (web socket closes in the background) how do applications like bumble and what's app continue to show near time notifications?
2. How can the socket continue to run in the background? Is there there better newer technology for doing this?

UPDATE
The question here is how to maintain a persistent websocket when the applications isn't in the foreground. I would like to know more about how iOS and android handle the situation when an application is minimised. Do the websockets continue to run? or are they closed? Do other libraries have to be used to make this keep running?

Comment: I don't know about Bumble but Whatsapp runs a background service to keep getting messages. You can also use push notifications to deliver messages in the background.

Comment: Hi Rishabh thanks for the response. Are push notifications native to the API for that device? I.e. does iOS and Android have their only push notifications?

Comment: I think you should read more about push notification for Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1 or Google: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications you can use this library for using websocket https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANDROID:**

As Android is focusing on the efficient way of using the battery, the system deprives the resources of the app when the app is in the background(Dependent). It is better to use the work manager to handle your background tasks.

Take a look https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics.html

Sample code

```
class GetMessages(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        getAndSaveMessages()
        return Result.success()
    }

    private fun getAndSaveMessages() {
         // get messages here
    }
}
```

Put this code in a Singleton class to access it from anywhere Like JobManager

```
    object JobManager{
 private fun syncMessages(){
        val loadMessages = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<GetMessages>(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        // Add tag to cancel the thread any time
        loadMessages.addTag("MESSAGES") 

        val myConstraints = Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        // Many other constraints are available, see the
                        // Constraints.Builder reference
                        .build()
        // Add constraints
        loadMessages.setConstraints(myConstraints)

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(loadMessages.buld())
    }

}
```

Now you can use `JobManager.syncMessages()`  from anywhere