# Android: Which Background Service to use?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-workmanager

I have an app where a user can perform a backup (offline) and restore (offline) on a button click. However, i don't know which background service is appropriate to use. Can someone advise me whether to use **WorkerManager** or **Service** in this case?

Comment: Worker manager is far better than service, as you know it will guarantee you to execute and you can add your constraints as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734905/websockets-on-android-and-ios/56735744#56735744 check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use `ForegroundService` as of the goal of using these services are Long Running Processes that Users should be informed and interact with it .

Consider when you try to backup when you Use `ForegroundService` then you can show to user

- The process left to end
- Cancel Backup
- Pause
- and etc

So I recommend you to use this approach .

Comment: While it is downloading or restoring data, i will need to update a progress tracker in the notification. Is Service still a better choice ? Or Loaders ?