# Migrate Android Job into Android Work manager

Tags: android

I have implemented Evernote Android Job in my android application. but i want to change it as WorkManager.

```
JobManager.create(this).addJobCreator(new MyJob());

public class MyJob implements JobCreator {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Job create(@NonNull String tag) {
        switch (tag) {
            case SyncMasterDataJOB.TAG:
                return new SyncMasterDataJOB();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Job Class:

```
public class SyncMasterDataJOB extends Job  {
    public static final String TAG = "job_note_sync";


    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Result onRunJob(@NonNull Params params) {

        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }


    public static void schedulePeriodic() {
        try{
        new JobRequest.Builder(SyncMasterDataJOB.TAG)                
               .setPeriodic(15*1000, 5*1000)
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .build()
                .schedule();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

}
```

How can i change Job into android workmanager.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734905/websockets-on-android-and-ios/56735744#56735744

Comment: Hi, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`WorkManager` is highly configurable and will allow you to create a `PeriodicWorkRequest` or a `OneTimeWorkRequest` these are guaranteed to succeed. `PeriodicWorkRequest` will fire when you schedule the work, as well as when you have specified in the timer. It will execute in the background even if the app is closed or backgrounded. If you didn't want your task to execute immediately you can use a PWR(PeriodicWorkRequest) with a [FlexInterval](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder#PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(java.lang.Class%3C?%2520extends%2520androidx.work.ListenableWorker%3E,%2520long,%2520java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%2520long,%2520java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). See the docs below for more info.

[WorkManager Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)

[WorkManager Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

[WorkmManager CodeLab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0)

For example, I created two PeriodicWorkRequests that refresh services and keeps the user logged in always by renewing their token. When the user authenticates the `PeriodicWorkRequest` is created. In my case, I didn't need it to fire right away as they have just received and cached this information so I utilized the FlexInterval. When the app is backgrounded or closed, the workers continue to refresh services every 12 hours and refresh the token every 6. It works like a charm.

Here is an example:

**Build Work:**

```
 override fun beginWork() {

        val periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                MyWorker::class.java,
                REPEAT_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MINUTES, // How often work should repeat
                // Flex not required.
                FLEX_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // Limits execution into a time window
                .setConstraints(
                     Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(
                                       NetworkType.CONNECTED).build())
                .addTag(MY_WORKER_TAG)
                .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                MY_UNIQUE_WORK,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                periodicLoginRequest)
```

**Worker:**

```
class MyWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
            // DO WORK HERE

            Result.success()
        } else {
            // HANDLE FAILURE HERE
            Result.failure()
        }
```

The above is a simple implementation, but it should give you the general idea.